# Why does my for loop doesn't count correct number of values that are equal to 'Online' in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

I am trying to count the number of people whose status is Online. I hate created a dictionary and also have created a count variable to keep track of people who are online. Below is my code and the error log. In below code, I expect count to be 2.

```
class Solution(object):

    def getStatus(self, status):
        count = 0

        for k, v in status.items():
            # I even tried to used json.load(status) to parse but it doesn't help

            if status[k].key() == "Online":
                count += 1
            else:
                pass
        return count


if __name__ == "__main__":
    statuses = {
        "Alice": "online",
        "Bob": "offline",
        "Eve": "online",
    }
    print(Solution().getStatus(statuses))
```

Below is my error log

```
  if status[k].key() == "Online":
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Comment: `if status[k].key() == "Online":` -> `if v.lower() == "online":`

Answer (score 2):

you want to check the value , you have access to it using variable `v`

you can use

```
if v == "online":
```

instead of

```
  if status[k].key() == "Online":
```

---

why are you getting the error ?

`status[k]` is the **string** which is the  value in the dict, so you can't call function `key()` on it. To verify this, just print `status[k]` in your loop to observe this.

Comment: Thank you so much, could you tell me in what scenario i should use key() ?

Comment: where did you read about this function called `key()` ?

Comment: I read about in a blog where it is used to check if certain key is present in a dictionary or not

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, `k` will Alice, Bob, etc and `v` will be "online" or "offline". There's no `key()` function to be called.

So for example:

```
if v == 'online':
    ....
```

That would work. Note that the evaluation is case-sensitive, and your example has mixed case, so that needs to be consistent.

Having said that, what you should use is [operator.countOf](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html), which is much simpler:

```
>>> statuses = {
...         "Alice": "online",
...         "Bob": "offline",
...         "Eve": "online",
... }
>>> from operator import countOf
>>> countOf(statuses.values(), 'online')
2
>>> countOf(statuses.values(), 'offline')
1
```

Comment: When should I use key()?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such method on anything that applies here, so I guess, never?